# How can I withdraw my bounty?

Tags: support, questions, bounties

Is it possible to withdraw a bounty after starting a bounty?

A week back I started a bounty for a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152142/why-my-yui-datatable-within-an-updatepanel-disappears-after-postback) on Stack Overflow.

I just found an answer for that question which was not on the answers list. Can I answer it and accept my own answer or withdraw the bounty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bounty is non-refundable, and the bounty is extracted permanently from your rep at the start of a bounty period.

You can answer and accept your own answer but no bounty will be awarded, and standard self-accept rules apply.

Comment: @jeff got ur point...

Comment: @chendur it is still in your best interests to post the answer, since it can generate upvotes for you

Comment: @chendur, even without any upvotes it's also in your best interest to post it as it simply improves the quality of these sites.

Comment: and @Arjan i ll do it..

Comment: Personally I'd rather give the points to a random person than see them evaporate.  I've waited a week or two on a bountied question, only to see it go un-answered.